# У меня выдает ошибку Syntax error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. Совсем не понимаю, в чем может быть проблема, ведь в другом месте это же работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Web3Modal from "web3modal"

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
    network: "mainnet",
    cacheProvider: true,
  })
  const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
  return (
     <div>  
     {connection === 'connected' ? (
       <a className="text-white">
         Address
       </a>
     ) : (
       <button className="text-white" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="alerted();">
         Connect
       </button>  
       )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
async function MyApp(...
^^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но после этого появляется такая ошибка: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @Ann теперь вызывайте эту функцию с `await` перед ней